# Prove that $h: A \cup B \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}_{n+m}$ is a bijection.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Consider $f: A \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}_n$ and $g: B \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}_m$, two bijections.

Prove that $h: A \cup B \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}_{n+m}$ is a bijection,

where $h(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) &\mbox{if } x \in A \\
g(x) + n & \mbox{if } x \in B \end{cases} $

I find it difficult due to cases.

According to proving $1-1$:

Let $x, y$ be 2 elements of $A\cup B$.

Suppose both $x$ and $y$ are in $A$:

$h(x)=h(y)$ $\rightarrow$ $f(x)=f(y)$ $\rightarrow$ $x=y$ since $f$ is injective.

Suppose both $x$ and $y$ are in $B$:

$h(x)=h(y)$ $\rightarrow$ $g(x)+n =g(y) +n $ $\rightarrow$ $x=y$ since $g$ is injective.

What about if $x$ $\in A$ and $y$ $\in B$ for example? We will get $f(x)= g(y) + n$ and then? I think this case will be excluded due to some reason that I didn't reach.

In proving surjectivity:

Let $y$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}_{n+m}$. For $y$ $\in \mathbb{N}_n$, there exists $x$ in $A\cup B$ such that $h(x)=f(x)=y$. After this point I got stuck, I feel like if I'm setting a condition that says: $n<m$, and really can't continue. Help me!

Answer (score 1):

- If $x$ $\in A$ and $y$ $\in B$, then $f(x) \le n < g(y)$ and so $f(x)\ne g(y)$.
- If $y \le n$, choose $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$. Otherwise, choose $x \in B$ such that $g(x)=y-n$.